# Exhaustive integer matching

Tags: rust

I try to exhaustively match integers like this:

```
fn main() {
    for test in range(std::u8::MIN, std::u8::MAX) {
        match test {
            0x00..0xff => {},
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
all.rs:3:9: 6:10 error: non-exhaustive patterns: `_` not covered [E0004]
all.rs:3         match test {
all.rs:4             0x00..0xff => {},
all.rs:5         }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

However, all possible values are covered. A quick check confirms this:

```
fn main() {
    for test in range(std::u8::MIN, std::u8::MAX) {
        match test {
            0x00..0xff => {},
            _ => fail!("impossible"),
        }
    }
}
```

And now compile and run it:

```
$ rustc all.rs
$ ./all
$
```

All possible values are covered, so why does rustc still want the obviously unreachable `_` arm?

Comment: Range checking of that type is simply not done, probably for simplicity. It could probably reasonably be added to the language. Incidentally, we have `unreachable!()` for your `fail!("impossible")`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: you might want to make this comment an answer, since it's as good as we'll get unless a compiler developer chimes in.

Comment: I believe it's [a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12483).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exhaustive integer matching [was stabilised](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2591) in Rust 1.33.0. The original example in the question [now works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73da6d0e446047efd24c64f519c08086) (updated to use the modern syntax for ranges).

```rust
fn main() {
    for i in std::u8::MIN..=std::u8::MAX {
        match i {
            0x00..=0xff => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that 1.33.0 is, as of 1 May 2021, two versions away from the stable version. I'm going to have to leave the pointless `_` arm in my code for (if I remember the schedule correctly) some 7 more weeks.

Comment: @DonHosek: Rust is currently at version 1.51.0.

Comment: That's what I get for looking at versions late at night, Interestingly, CLion with the Rust plugin flags it as an error without the unreachable arm but it compiles fine on the same machine. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the referenced [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12483), Rust's exhaustiveness checking is based entirely on enums and never values, so this fails because `u8` simply isn't an enum type.

Answer (score -2):

I'd imagine the compile just see that you are matching on type `u8` (though any number type would work for this argument), and for the sake of simplicity does not actually check that your patterns cover the full range. It's much easier for the compiler to expect you to have a 'catch all' with `_` and make the developer handle it.

Also consider that it's very stupid to use a `match` when you are going to match every result any way, in that case you should just use the value.

Comment: He probably just baked the example to be as small as possible, and is generally interested in multiple sub-ranges.

Comment: I'd still argue it good practice to end with `_ => unreachable()`. If you *really* think you are handling every possible input, then why not put your money where your mouth is?